# Splitting a red-black tree destructively?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, priority-queue, red-black-tree

I would like to implement a priority queue using a red-black tree. Using a binary heap is O(log n) worst case for deletion, and I will be removing many keys from the queue at once, so I want O(log n) worst case for the bulk deletion, rather than O(m log n) worst case, where m is the number of keys being removed at once. I will probably only be removing a minority of the keys.

I will not need the old tree anymore. How can I split a red-black tree destructively (which apparently can somehow be done in O(log n)) to accomplish this, while maintaining the black height invariant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implementation of the algorithm you need in the archive at
https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/download/releases%2FCGAL-5.0.3/CGAL-5.0.3.zip

in the file include/cgal/MultiSet.h starting at line 2617 the function is Multiset<Type, Compare, Allocator>::split

The algorithm is also described in the paper at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjpqfz_sKrrAhVkFjQIHbnbDYYQFjADegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.109.4875%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw26DS8sY7M2fmunxpDfXUZn

Comment: Thank you very much, seeing an actual implementation is invaluable!